# Lambda of "x => { throw .. }" inferred to match Func<T,Task> in overloaded method?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, overloading, type-inference

I don't understand why C# ends up executing an incorrect extension method in the following LINQPad code:

```
void Main()
{
    // Actual: Sync Action
    "Expected: Sync Action".Run(x => { x.Dump(); });

    // Actual: Async Task
    "Expected: Async Task".Run(async x => { await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => x.Dump()); });

    // Actual: Async Task!!
    "Expected: Sync Action".Run(x => { throw new Exception("Meh"); });
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static void Run<T>(this T instance, Action<T> action)
    {
        "Actual: Sync Action".Dump();
        action(instance);
    }

    public static void Run<T>(this T instance, Func<T, System.Threading.Tasks.Task> func)
    {
        "Actual: Async Task".Dump();
        func(instance).Wait();
    }
}
```

Why does the compiler think that the lambda returns a Task here?

I expected to see "Actual: Sync Action" in the third call to Run() since nothing in the lambda indicates that this is a Func returning Task.

Comment: This IS Linqpad code.. Nothing special except for the Dump() extension method.

Comment: You're right, it's actually unrelated to the extension method since I was able to reproduce with normal overloaded methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply an overload resolution issue. Clearly, the lambda `x => { throw new Exception("Meh"); }` can be converted to either an `Action<T>` or to a `Func<T, SomeNonVoidType>` (as well as to many other delegate types irrelevant to this question). It's simply C#'s overload resolution rules that prefer the latter in this case.

Here's a more representative example:

```
void Main()
{
    // Output: Func<T, int>
    "Test".WhatsThis(x => { throw new Exception("Meh"); });
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static void WhatsThis<T>(this T dummy, Action<T> action)
    {
       "Action<T>".Dump();
    }
    public static void WhatsThis<T>(this T dummy, Func<T, int> func)
    {
       "Func<T, int>".Dump();
    }
}
```

As for *why* this is the case, I'm not 100% sure, but a casual look at the [spec](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029) shows me the below likely explanation (emphasis mine):

> 7.5.3 Overload resolution
>
> [...]
>
> 7.5.3.3 Better conversion from expression
>
> Given an implicit conversion C1 that converts from an expression E to a type T1, and an implicit conversion C2 that converts from an expression E to a type T2, C1 is a better conversion than C2 if at least one of the following holds:
>
> [...]
>
> • E is an anonymous function, T1 is either a delegate type D1 or an expression tree type
>   `Expression<D1>`, T2 is either a delegate type D2 or an expression tree
>   type `Expression<D2>` and one of the following holds:
>
> [...]
>
> **•   D1 has a return type Y, and D2 is void returning**

Comment: Thanks for explaining what may be going on. In the second invocation above I explicitly specify "async x =>" which may hint the compiler that we're dealing with a lambda returning Task here. In absence of the async keyword, does it make sense to "default" to the func instead of the action or is it just an arbitrary choice?

Comment: Clearly, the spec thinks of a non-void returning delegate as "better" / "more specific" than a void one in this context. It does not provide any indication as to why, though. I suspect the annotated specification might reveal more (I don't have a copy, sadly). If someone like Eric Lippert sees this question, odds are good that we might get a more definitive explanation.

Comment: @ichen: The `async` keyword does not influence the type of the lambda. I believe the intent of the overload resolution rules are to avoid `async void` lambdas, [which are especially tricky](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/08/10265476.aspx).

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes this makes sense. I also see that you commented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395826/explicitly-use-a-functask-for-asynchronous-lambda-function-when-action-overloa) that Microsoft deliberately chose to select the Func returning task delegate over the Action. It seems that the only way to work around this gotcha is to explicitly instantiate the desired delegate.