# Ambiguous extension method call

Tags: c#

This code won't compile:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

static class Extensions {
    public static void Foo(this A a, Exception e = null, string memberName = "") {
    }

    public static void Foo<T>(this A a, T t, Exception e = null, string memberName = "")
        where T : class, IB {
    }
}

interface IB { }

class A { }

class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var a = new A();
        var e = new Exception();

        a.Foo(e); //<- Compile error "ambiguous call"
    }
}
```

But if I delete last `string` arguments everything is fine:

```
    public static void Foo(this A a, Exception e = null) {
    }

    public static void Foo<T>(this A a, T t, Exception e = null)
        where T : class, IB {
    }
```

Question is - why these optional `string` arguments break compiler's choice of method call?

**Added:** 
Clarified question: I dont get why compiler can't choose right overload in the first case but could do it in second one?

**Edited:** 
`[CallerMemberName]` attribute is not a cause of a problem here so I've deleted it from question.

Comment: Just to clarify: Removing the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute alone *has no* effect, the compiler outputs an error. Removing the whole argument `[CallerMemberName] string memberName = ""` *has* an effect, the code compiles. This is what I observe. Right?

Comment: **C# Specification: 7.5.3.2 Better function member:** *Otherwise if all parameters of MP have a corresponding argument whereas default arguments need to be substituted for at least one optional parameter in MQ then MP is better than MQ.* That rule is applied in second case, but can not be applied in first case.

Comment: If you only remove the attribute `[CallerMemberName]`, but keep the parameter `string memberName = ""` in both methods, then what happens? Edit: @OndrejTucny already said that, I see after posting. Still a good question.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Tried that in LINQPad 4.57 (C# 5) and it won't compile.

Comment: @OndrejTucny right. I just repeated code from my project.

Comment: @Szer that is indeed an Ambiguous call because of the optional parameters for e and memberName the compiler is assuming that `T t` is `Exception t`

Comment: @Moes Ok, fine. Why compiler not assuming the same without last `string` parameters?

Comment: @Moes It is clear enough, I guess, why both overloads could apply (the constraint on `T` in the generic overload is not considered this early in the algorithm). This question is about why it works fine in the truncated example. For `T t` could match `Exception t` in that case too. I think you will just have to read the C# Specification carefully. Overload resolution is really complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@PetSerAl pointed to the spec in the comments already, but let me translate that to plain English:

The C# language has a rule that says an overload without omitted defaulted arguments is preferred over an overload with omitted defaulted arguments. This rule makes `Foo(this A a, Exception e = null)` a better match than `Foo(this A a, T t, Exception e = null)`.

The C# language does not have a rule saying that an overload with one omitted defaulted argument is preferred over an overload with two omitted defaulted arguments. Because it does not have such a rule, `Foo(this A a, Exception e = null, string s = "")` is *not* preferred over `Foo<T>(this A a, T t, Exception e = null, string s = "")`.

The easiest way to avoid this problem would normally be by providing additional overloads, instead of using default parameter values. You need default parameter values for `CallerMemberName` to work, but you can provide additional overloads that omit the `Exception`, and forward to the real implementation by passing `null` for that.

Note: ensuring that `Foo<T>(this A a, T t, string s = "")` doesn't get picked when `Foo(this A a, Exception e, string s = "")` is available is going to be a tricky problem regardless. If your variable is statically typed as `Exception`, then the non-generic method will be preferred, but if it's statically typed as e.g. `ArgumentException`, then `T=ArgumentException` is a better match than the base class `Exception`, and the error in `T=ArgumentException` will be detected too late to pick the method you want to call. Perhaps it would be safest to place `T` *after* `Exception`, and always require an exception being passed in (possibly `null`) when the generic method is intended.

Comment: Great answer. Does it mean that constraints such as `where T : class, IB` are completely ignored by compiler when it comes to overload resolution?

Comment: @Szer yes, [generic constraints are not part of a method's signature.](@Szer yes, generic [constraints are not part of a methods signature.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/)

Comment: Here is an exact quote from the C# Language Specification: _• Otherwise if all parameters of MP have a corresponding argument whereas default arguments need to be substituted for at least one optional parameter in MQ then MP is better than MQ._

Comment: @Szer InBetween is right, and that can cause a problem I missed even when you avoid the default parameter values. Now edited to try to address that too.

Comment: I guess the C# language rule that does exist ensures we can always, with enough effort of casting and giving all parameters explicitly even if they have their default values (or inferred values for type parameters), call any specific overload "directly".

Comment: What happens, in the original question, if you _name_ the parameter, as in `a.Foo(e: e);`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That's a valid way of resolving the ambiguity, [and I've used and recommended it myself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20396765/743382), but only when it's reasonable to assume the parameter names aren't going to change.