# Why does this Assert.Throws call resolve this way?

Tags: c#, xunit

Using xUnit's `Assert.Throws`, I stumbled upon this (to me) hard to explain overload resolution issue. In xUnit, this method is [marked obsolete](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/master/ExceptionAsserts.cs):

```
[Obsolete("You must call Assert.ThrowsAsync<T> (and await the result) " +
           "when testing async code.", true)]        
public static T Throws<T>(Func<Task> testCode) where T : Exception 
{ throw new NotImplementedException(); }
```

The question is, why does an inline statement lambda (or expression) that simply throws an exception resolve to this overload (and therefore doesn't compile)?

```
using System;
using Xunit;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // this compiles (of course)
        // resolves into the overload accepting an `Action`
        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => ThrowException());
        // line below gives error CS0619 'Assert.Throws<T>(Func<Task>)' is obsolete: 
        // 'You must call Assert.ThrowsAsync<T> (and await the result) when testing async code.'    
        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => { throw new Exception(); });
    }

    static void ThrowException()
    {
        throw new Exception("Some message");
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the overload that this resolves into: `Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => ThrowException());`

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395826/explicitly-use-a-functask-for-asynchronous-lambda-function-when-action-overloa#20395969

Comment: @SelmanGenç the overload accepting an `Action`

Comment: a lambda that only throws could have *any* possible return type. I'm not surprised the system's confused.

Comment: Are you sure the first line does not cause a warning, too?. The `ObsoleteAttribute` does not differentiate, so both lines should yield a warning.

Comment: @Sefe no warning on my machine. It resolves to a different overload.

Comment: `Func<Task>` does take precedence over `Action` when resolving overloads. I remember seeing an answer to a similar question by @EricLippert, couldn't find it right away but it's out there.

Comment: @Noseratio This is true for async functions. See here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#inferred-return-type

Comment: @FCin, not only for async functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20418228/1768303

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete example which doesn't involve `Task`, to remove any hint of asynchrony being involved:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Method(Action action)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Action");
    }

    static void Method(Func<int> func)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Func<int>");
    }

    static void ThrowException()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Resolvse to the Action overload
        Method(() => ThrowException());
        // Resolves to the Func<int> overload
        Method(() => { throw new Exception(); });        
    }
}
```

Using section numbering from [ECMA 334 (5th edition)](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm), we're interested in section 12.6.4 - overload resolution. The two important steps are:

- Identify applicable methods (12.6.4.2)
- Identify the *best* method (12.6.4.3)

We'll look at each call in turn

### Call 1: `() => ThrowException()`

Let's start with the first call, which has an argument of `() => ThrowException()`. To check for applicability, we need a conversion from that argument to either `Action` or `Func<int>`. We can check that without involving overloading at all:

```
// Fine
Action action = () => ThrowException();
// Fails to compile:
// error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int'
// error CS1662: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because 
// some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the 
// delegate return type
Func<int> func = () => ThrowException();
```

The CS1662 error is a little unfortunately worded in this case - it's not that there's a return type in the block that's not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type, it's that there *isn't* a return type in the lambda expression at all. The spec way of preventing this is in section 11.7.1. None of the permitted conversions there work. The closest is this (where F is the lambda expression and D is `Func<int>`):

> If the body of `F` is an expression, and either `F` is non-async and `D` has a non-void return type `T`, or `F` is async and `D` has a return type `Task<T>`, then when each parameter of F is given the type of the corresponding parameter in `D`, the body of `F` is a valid expression (w.r.t §12) that is implicitly convertible to `T`.

In this case the expression `ThrowException` is *not* implicitly convertible to `int`, hence the error.

All of this means that only the first method is applicable for `() => ThrowException()`. Our pick for "best function member" is really easy when the set of applicable function members only has a single entry...

### Call 2: `() => { throw new Exception(); }`

Now let's look at the second call, which has `() => { throw new Exception(); }` as the argument. Let's try the same conversions:

```
// Fine
Action action = () => { throw new Exception(); };
// Fine
Func<int> func = () => { throw new Exception(); };
```

Both conversions work here. The latter one works because of *this* bullet from 11.7.1:

> If the body of `F` is a statement block, and either `F` is non-async and `D` has a
>   non-void return type `T`, or `F` is async and `D` has a return type `Task<T>`,
>   then when each parameter of `F` is given the type of the corresponding parameter in
>   `D`, the body of `F` is a valid statement block (w.r.t §13.3) with a nonreachable
>   end point in which each return statement specifies an expression that is implicitly
>   convertible to `T`.

I realize it sounds odd that this works, but:

- The end point of the block is not reachable
- There are no return statements, so the condition of "each return statement specifies [...]" is indeed met

To put it another way: you *could* use that block as the body of a method that's declared to return `int`.

That means *both* our methods are applicable in this case.

#### So which is better?

Now we need to look at section 12.6.4.3 to work out which method will actually be picked.

There are *lots* of rules here, but the one that decides things here is the conversion from the lambda expression to either `Action` or `Func<int>`. That's resolved in 12.6.4.4 (better conversion from expression):

> Given an implicit conversion C1 that converts from an expression E to a type T1, and an implicit conversion C2 that converts from an expression E to a type T2, C1 is a better conversion than C2 if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - ...
> - E is an anonymous function, T1 is either a delegate type D1 or an expression tree 
>     type `Expression<D1>`, T2 is either a delegate type D2 or an expression tree type `Expression<D2>` and
>     one of the following holds:
>
>   - D1 is a better conversion target than D2
>   - D1 and D2 have identical parameter lists, and one of the following holds:
>
>     - D1 has a return type Y1, and D2 has a return type Y2, an inferred return type X exists for E in the context of that parameter list (§12.6.3.13), and the conversion from X to Y1 is better than the conversion from X to Y2
>     - E is async [... - skipped because it's not]
>     - **D1 has a return type Y, and D2 is void returning**

The part I've put in bold is the important bit. When you consider the following scenario:

- E is `() => { throw new Exception(); }`
- T1 is `Func<int>` (so D1 is `Func<int>` too)
- T2 is `Action` (so D2 is `Action` too)

... then both D1 and D2 have empty parameter lists, but D1 has a return type `int`, and D2 is void returning.

Therefore the conversion to `Func<int>` is better than the conversion to `Action`... which means that `Method(Action)` is a better function member than `Member(Func<int>)` for the second call.

Phew! Don't you just love overload resolution?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to reproduce this, given the function declarations:

```
static void CallFunction(Action action) { }

static void CallFunction(Func<Task> func) { }
```

And calling them:

```
CallFunction(() => ThrowException());
CallFunction(() => { throw new Exception(); });
```

The second one resolves into `CallFunction(Func<Task> func)` overload. The weird thing is if I change the body like this:

```
CallFunction(() => { int x = 1; });
```

It resolves to `CallFunction(Action action)` overload.

If the last statement in the body is a throw statement, I guess the compiler thinks method is returning something, and picks the closest -more specific- overload to that scenario which is `Func<Task>`.

The closest thing I found in the documentation is this:

7.5.2.12 Inferred return type

> • If F is async and the body of F is either an expression classified as nothing (§7.1), or a statement block where no return statements have expressions, **the inferred return type is System.Threading.Tasks.Task**

The function here is a statement block, but it's not async though. Note that I'm not saying *this exact rule applies here*. Still I'm guessing it's related to this.

[This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/21/never-say-never-part-one/) from Eric Lippert explains it better. (thanks for the comment @Damien_The_Unbeliever).

Comment: The question is why it thinks it is returning something.

Comment: @FCin I know, I don't have a definitive answer for that, I'm looking into the specs to find something.

Comment: @FCin - because a method that only throws is a *valid* implementation for every possible return type (and `void`)

Comment: `() => { int x = 1; }` calls 1. `() => { int x = 1; throw new Exception(); }` calls 2. `() => { int x = 1; throw new Exception(); return; }` and `() => { throw new Exception(); return; }`call 1.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So why didn't it choose `Action` over `Func<Task>`? Second question, shouldn't it print an error, because of ambigous overload?

Comment: @FCin - there is a reason, and I think it's to do with `Func<Task>` being a *better* match that `Action` if it can (as here) choose between them. I swear Eric Lippert has written about this. I found the start here - [Never say Never, part one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/21/never-say-never-part-one/)

Comment: I have added the closest explanation to this in docs. still, not the exact explanation but must be related to this somehow.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that article is on point, added to the answer.

Comment: I've gone into more detail in my answer. The async part is an unfortunate red herring. Eric's article gives the explanation for why the conversion to `Func<...>` is valid - my answer explains that and also why it's a *better* conversion than the conversion to `Action`.

Comment: Basically the choice made by the designers here is that being compatible with a method that says it can return *something of some type* is "more specific" than a method which returns nothing at all.  This is a pretty arbitrary choice!  There's an argument to be made that we know the *exact behaviour* on return of a void method -- it returns nothing -- and we don't know the exact behaviour of a non-void method on return, because it can return any value of its type, and so the void method is more specific.  Ultimately it's a judgment call by the designers.